# Completely Deny Access To Files C++

Tags: c++

I know with SetNamedSecurityInfo() we can limit or deny access to files but the permissions can be changed easily by right clicking on the file going to security tab and changing what we want for different user groups. But consider programs like GiliSoft. when it locks a file even the administrators can't change the permission and access them. It may be a kind of bug for windows. It's funny that Administrator can lock a file but he can't unlock and access it again. Anyway I wanna know how to do this. Anyone knows?

Comment: Serverfault would be a better place to ask about Windows security.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. If you can explain why you need this feature, we can offer relevant suggestions.

Comment: @egrunin I want to change the permissions in order to avoid someone removes a specific file

Comment: Yes, but *why* do you want to keep them from deleting the file? If they know enough to change file permissions, don't you trust them? Or are you protecting your system from sabotage?

Comment: There many programs like what I mentioned and it's strange that you ask their developers why do you make these? what do you want to know exactly? If you can help doing this so tell what you know. Otherwise why are you so curious? By the way this is a part of project that i'm working on. I should make very hard (of course can't be impossible) for the user to delete the file and I decided to ask here before I use API hook.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm putting this in an "answer" because comments don't allow paragraphs, and this is too long for one paragraph.)

There is literally no way to be 100% sure your file won't be deleted. The question becomes *how far do you want to go?* You can:

- hide the file in the usual way
- hide the file from the OS with a hook
- hide the file from the OS with a rootkit
- mark the file read-only in the usual way
- 'lock' the file by having a process open it
- keep two processes running, each of which restarts the other and both of which lock the file
- keep a daemon running which lets you delete the file, but replaces it immediately
- these processes can be hidden in various ways, of course

These are *not* 'theoretical' solutions, as anyone who has work with viruses and anti-viruses can tell you.

And of course, I forgot to ask what OS you're using...

Comment: The idea 'Two process that restarting each other' is perfect. I think this way even with coded termination program both of them can't be terminated at once.

Answer (score 0):

An admin can always change permission of a file - however, they might have to take ownership of it first.

Comment: Well if they take ownership, whats the new ownership? how do they do this? And also the program needs to be able to change the permissions later while user wants to. Also they can limit the access as well, for example Deny write ...

Comment: right click open up the security tab, click advanced, see the 'owner' tab. Once you are the owner, you can change whatever permissions you like on 'your' file.

Comment: I don't have it installed now to check. What does the program change owner to? Does it create a new user group? do you have any idea?